# How to prevent AngularJS interpolation on a div?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

Is there a way to prevent interpolation on a div? I want to grab the raw html from it and interpolate manually by injecting `$interpolate` like this:

```
$scope.report = $interpolate($("#myDiv").html())($scope);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline templates declared using script tag (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)

```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myDivTemplate">
      Hello my name is {{name}}
  </script>
```

Then interpolate it as

```
$scope.report = $interpolate($("#myDivTemplate").html())($scope);
```

Comment: Since you already defined the template, wouldn't it be better to grab it from the template cache? `$interpolate($templateCache.get('myDivTemplate'))($scope);`

Comment: Yes. This way you won't feel guilty of doing DOM manipulation anywhere that's not inside a directive. Also, even better is to use `$http` with `cache: $templateCache`, because this way you don't have to assume that the template _will always_ be in the page.

Comment: Using `$templateCache.get('myDivTemplate')` would be more cleaner approach

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ngNonBindable`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) directive. Taken from the docs:

```
<div>Normal: {{1 + 2}}</div> // => Normal: 3
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div> // => Ignored: {{1+2}}
```

However, beware that this probably won't compile other directives present in that element.

---

Another option (which is the most correct in my opinion) is to create a directive and capture the content of the element in the compile phase, and then only interpolate it when you need:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function( $interpolate ) {
  return {
    compile: function( tElement ) {
      var raw = tElement.html();
      return function( scope, element ) {
        var interpolated = $interpolate( raw )( scope );
        // do something with it
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. ngNonBindable works, but I think using a template is probably the right thing for me.